# Sum of rows and columns of a positive and invertible matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-theory, spectral-graph-theory

Let's assume a square matrix **M**$\in \mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R_0^+})^{n\times n}$, meaning its generic entry $m_{i,j} >0$ for any  $i,j=1,\dots,n$, and moreover **M** is invertible.
Is it possible to demonstrate that if $\sum_{i}\sum_{j}m_{i,j}=1$, then $\sum_{j=1}^nm_{i,j}=\sum_{j=1}^nm_{j,i}$ for any chosen $i \in \{1,\dots,n\}$? Which theoretical result may I use? I think that it would be possible to demonstrate it by induction, but I'm more interested in linking it with existing theory results which at the moment I cannot recall.
Thanks in advance.

Leonardo Angeli

Comment: What does primitive mean?

Comment: This definitely isn't true. Consider $M=\frac1nxe^T$, where $e$ is the vector of ones and $x$ is a positive vector such that $\sum_ix_i=1$, all elements of $x$ are distinct and none of the elements of $x$ is equal to $\frac{1}{n^2}$.

Comment: @user1551 thanks for your reply. I'm sorry I don't get your counterexample. If I understood correctly the product between $x$ and $e^T$ has to be intended as a Hadamard product right? Well, in that case, M collapses to a k-dimensional vector, k being the dimension of $x,e$, which is not in the space of my hypothesis.

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan a primitive matrix $\mathbf{M}$ is non-negative, i.e. $m_{ij}\ge 0, \forall i,j$ , and there exists an integer $k>0$ s.t. $ \mathbf{M}^k$ is strictly positive, i.e. its components are all strictly positive. This implies that the spectral radius $\lambda$ of $\mathbf{M}$ is one of its eigenvalues and it is algebraically simple, real and positive. Furthermore, the correspondent right and left eigenvectors have strictly positive components.

Comment: @LeonardoAngeli $xe^T$ is the usual mutiplication of the $n\times 1$ matrix $x$ by the $1\times n$ matrix $e^T$. That is $m_{ij}=x_i$.

Comment: Oh sorry, this is clear and of course, this trivially solves my dilemma. Thank you.

Comment: @LeonardoAngeli If you assume that all entries are strictly positive, it no use assuming that the matrix is primitive.

Comment: @LeonardoAngeli Sorry, I meant $m_{ij}=\color{red}{\frac{1}{n}}x_i$.

Comment: Dear all, thanks for your quick and sharp comments. The assumption of a primitive matrix is indeed redundant @ChristopheLeuridan and I actually forgot an additional requirement that the matrix is nonsingular. I edited the main text and of course, the counterexample is not valid in this case . Apologies for wasting your time

Comment: You take any matrix with strictly positive entries, so the choices of the entries are independent. How can you hope a strong result (sum over row i equal to sum over column i) with so poor assumptions? Assuming that all entries add up to 1 does not change anything (since the desired conclusion is invariant by a multiplication of the matrix by a constant), assuming that the matrix is invertible also does not change anything (since the invertible matrix form a dense open set).